# What's the difference between live and not live collection in Javascript selectors?

Tags: javascript

How can I know what is the difference between live and not live collection.

*According to my research:*

A **live** is: when the changes in the DOM are reflected in the collection. The content suffers the change when a node is modified.

A **Not Live** is : when any change in the DOM does not affect the content of the collection.

document.getElementsByClassName() is an HTMLCollection, and is live.

document.getElementsByTagName() is an HTMLCollection, and is live.

document.getElementsByName() is a NodeList and is live.

document.querySelectorAll() is a NodeList and is not live.

**Why document.querySelectorAll is not live?**

*I know that :*

**HTMLCollection** only contains Elements Nodes
**NodeList** contains Element Nodes and Text Nodes.

Comment: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Answer (score 12):

These

```
document.getElementsByClassName()
document.getElementsByTagName()
document.getElementsByName()
```

are live because they are observers of internal collections maintained by engines. That maintenance is not strictly required but is easy to achieve.

```
document.querySelectorAll()
```

is not live because result gets computed each time you request it. 
Maintenance of live collection is too expensive as each modification (content, attributes, classes) of the DOM in this case will require re-evaluation of each element in the collection - `O(N*M)` task where N is the number of all elements in the DOM (worst case) and M number of active `querySelectorAll()` collections.

Comment: i was thinking that too, but then how does CSS apply such selectors so quickly?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so quickly. To find out all styles of all elements in the DOM is a `O(N*S)` task where N is a number of DOM elements and S is a number of style rules (selectors to be precise). You can read my article here:  http://www.terrainformatica.com/2008/07/css-selectors-and-computational-complexity/

Answer (score 2):

From the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection)

> A *collection* is an object that represents a lists of DOM nodes. A
>   [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) can be either *live* or *static*. Unless otherwise
>   stated, a [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) must be [live](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection-live).
>
> If a [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) is [live](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection-live), then the attributes and methods on
>   that object must operate on the actual underlying data, not a snapshot
>   of the data.
>
> When a [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) is created, a filter and a root are associated
>   with it.
>
> The [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) then *represents* a view of the subtree rooted at
>   the [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection)'s root, containing only nodes that match the given
>   filter. The view is linear. In the absence of specific requirements to
>   the contrary, the nodes within the [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-collection) must be sorted in
>   [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order).

The reasoning to make the `querySelectorAll` return a static `NodeList` may be to be able to allow more complex selectors.

For example, Selectors L4 may introduce things like the [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) pseudo-class. Probably, since it can't be implemented in a reasonable performance, it will only be available in `querySelectorAll` but not in stylesheets.

If the collection returned by `querySelectorAll` was live, then those complex selectors would need to be recalculated lots of times, and that would be so expensive.

Comment: if it's quick enough to apply styles, however fast/slow that is, why isn't is quick enough to maintain a collection?

Comment: @dandavis Finding the elements that match a complex selector is OK if you only do it once, but recalculating them each time the DOM is modified is too expensive.

Comment: CSS manages to keep them updated each time the DOM is modified. I agree with your answer, it makes sense, but it begs the question of how stylesheets manage to be quick enough to apply and keep applied...

Comment: @dandavis Yes, stylesheets are like live collections. That's why expensive selectors like `:has()` will be allowed in `querySelectorAll` but probably not in stylesheets.

Comment: a lot's good enough for stylesheets today. i'm not trying to pick on you, it just seems like a rip-off to JS...