# Append element from XML to div, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

EDIT: made title more specific to address duplicate question problem.

I have an HTML page that has a `button` and a `div`. When the user clicks the button, a function runs an `XMLHttpRequest` to get a table from an XML file. The table should be inserted into the `div`.

The AJAX request returns an `object Element` to my variable. How can I get the content of that variable (i.e., the `<table><tr><td>...` etc. from the XML file) to insert into the `div`?

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function table_loadContent() {

    var request;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log("HTTPRequest");

    } else {

        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        console.log("ActiveX");

    }

    request.open('GET', 'myXMLFile.xml');

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {

            var newTable = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('table');
            document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTable);

        }

    }

    request.send();

}
```

Variations that I've tried that don't work:

- `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myVar;`
- `document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myVar);`
- `document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(myVar[0]);`
- same as above but using a second variable to hold a `.toString()` version
- tried declaring the XML file as `XML` and as `HTML`
- `var newTable = request.responseXML.getElementById('myTable')`;

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` return an array of tables! You have to address only one (maybe the first) element. use `console.log(newTable)` for debug.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` is an HTML Collection does not make sense with appendChild

Comment: Can you provide more details about what's inside your XML file? Vanilla dom methods work with XML since HTML is a subset of XML. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

But everything depends on what is actually found inside your .xml file as it could be badly formatted and prevent the parsing to occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read xml file contents in jQuery and display in html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220873/how-to-read-xml-file-contents-in-jquery-and-display-in-html-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered the solution:

### By changing the lines:

var newTable = request.**responseXML.getElementsByTagName('table')**
document.getElementById('myDiv')**.appendChild(newTable)**

### to:

var newTable = request.**responseText**
document.getElementById('myDiv').**innerHTML = newTable**

it works as we'd like it to. (Edit frustration: I can't get it to break lines properly)

Answer (score 0):

In the next code:

```
var newTable = request.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('table');
```

The `newTable` variable is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), it is not an element.

If you want to append just the first element in the collection you can use:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newTable[0]);
```

If you want to add all the nodes inside the collection you need to iterate in the collection and add to the `div` each element contained in it:

```
var newTable = request.responseXML.documentElement.querySelectorAll('table');

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

[].forEach.call(newTable, function (table) {

    myDiv.appendChild(table)

});
```

> **NOTES:**
>   1 - I've used `querySelectorAll` method because it is [a not-live HTMLCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486199/whats-the-difference-between-live-and-not-live-collection-in-javascript-selecto) and can be used to modify the `DOM` without modifying the collection.
>   2 - Use the `documentElement` property of the `responseXML` to ensure that you are selecting the main document node.

Comment: I implemented the solution I posted, which works well enough to display the table in my div, and receive CSS styling. But now I'm trying to add JS and it doesn't seem to be able to recognize the table. Is my method causing this? Will your method, or another method, solve it?

Comment: Could you post the `XML` that you are using?

Comment: Ok, we had another breakthrough. Here's what's happening: we have a dropdown menu that calls the function that gets a table from one of two files depending on the value of the menu; once the table is added to the div another function is called that checks the table, but it doesn't work until you change the table a second time, in which case it's able to target the initial table. So it's one step behind. TableCheck1 finds no table; TableCheck2 finds table 1; TableCheck3 finds table 2, etc. The next question is how do we wait until the table is loaded before calling the TableCheck function?

Comment: You have an `onreadystatechange` in your code, execute the function once the `XML` has loaded and the table has been inserted into the `DOM`.

Comment: Could you provide a code example for doing that? (This is all much appreciated, by the way)

Comment: I think that it is better you open another question with that specific problem, in this way you will get more help.